# Release resources in .Net C#

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, resources

I'm new to C# and .NET, ,and have been reading around about it.

I need to know why and when do I need to release resources? Doesn't the garbage collector take care of everything? When do I need to implement IDisposable, and how is it different from destructor in C++?

Also, if my program is rather small i.e. a screensaver, do I need to care about releasing resources?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this link - http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/oreilly/dotnet/news/programmingCsharp_0801.html

Comment: This question is also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317184/c-using-keyword-when-and-when-not-to-use-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to worry about releasing resources to unmanaged code - anything outside the .NET framework. For example, a database connection or a file on the OS.

The garbage collector deals with managed code - code in the .NET framework.

Even a small application may need to release unmanaged resources, for example it may write to a local text file. When you have finished with the resource you need to ensure the object's Dispose method is called. The [using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement simplifies the syntax:

```
using (TextWriter w = File.CreateText("test.txt"))
{
    w.WriteLine("Test Line 1");
}
```

The TextWriter object implements the IDisposable interface so as soon as the using block is finished the Dispose method is called and the object can be garbage collected. The actual time of collection cannot be guaranteed.

If you create your own classes that need to be Disposed of properly you will need to implement the IDisposable interface and Dispose pattern yourself. On a simple application you probably won't need to do this, if you do [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/idisposable.aspx) is a good resource.

Answer (score 15):

The garbage collector is only aware of memory. That's fine for memory, because one bit of memory is pretty much as good as any other, so long as you've got enough of it. (This is all modulo cache coherency etc.)

Now compare that with file handles. The operating system could have plenty of room to allocate more file handles - but if you've left a handle open to a particular file, no-one else will be able to open *that particular file* for writing. You should tell the system when you're done with a handle - usually by closing the relevant stream - as soon as you're finished, and do so in a way that closes it even if an exception is thrown. This is usually done with a `using` statement, which is like a try/finally with a call to `Dispose` in the finally block.

Destructors in C++ are *very* different from .NET finalizers, as C++ destructors are deterministic - they're automatically called when the relevant variable falls out of scope, for example. Finalizers are run by the garbage collector *at some point* after an object is no longer referenced by any "live" objects, but the timing is unpredictable. (In some rare cases, it may *never* happen.)

You should implement `IDisposable` yourself if you have any clean-up which should be done deterministically - typically that's the case if one of your instance variables *also* implements `IDisposable`. It's pretty rare these days to need to implement a finalizer yourself - you usually only need one if you have a *direct* hold on operating system handles, usually in the form of `IntPtr`; `SafeHandle` makes all of this a lot easier and frees you from having to write the finalizer yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Resources are of two kinds - managed, and unmanaged. Managed resources will be cleaned up by the garbage collector if you let it - that is, if you release any reference to the object. However, the garbage collection does not know how to release unmanaged resources that a managed object holds - file handles, and other OS resources for example.

IDisposable is best practice when there's a managed resource you want released promptly (like a database connection), and vital when there are unmanaged resources which you need to have released. The typical pattern:

```
public void Dispose()
protected void Dispose(bool disposing)
```

Lets you ensure that unmanaged resources are released whether by the `Dispose` method or by object finalisation.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to release memory in managed objects like strings or arrays - that is handled by the garbage collector.

You should clean up operating system resources and some unmanaged objects when you have finished using them. If you open a file you should always remember to close that file when you have finished using it. If you open a file exclusively and forget to close, the next time you try to open that file it might still be locked. If something implements `IDisposable`, you should definitely consider whether you need to close it properly. The documentation will usually tell you what the `Dispose` method does and when it should be called.

If you do forget, the garbage collector will eventually run the finalizer which should clean up the object correctly and release the unmanaged resources, but this does not happen immediately after the object becomes eligible for garbage collection, and it in fact might not run at all.

Also it is useful to know about the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28VS.80%29.aspx) statement.

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector releases MEMORY and cleans up - through disposition - elemetns it removes. BUT: IT only does so when it has memory pressure.

THis is seriously idiotic for ressources whree I may want to explicitely release them. Save to file, for example, is supposed to: Open the file, write out the data and - close the file, so it can be copied away by the user if he wants, WITHOUT waiting for the GC to come around and release the memory for the file object, which may not happen for hours.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to worry about precious resources. Most objects you create while programming do not fit into this category. As you say, the garbage collector will take care of these.

What you do need to be mindful of is objects that implement IDisposable, which is an indication that the resources it owns are precious and should not wait for the finalizer thread to be cleaned up. The only time you would need to implement IDisposable is on classes that own a) objects that implement IDisposable (such as a file stream), or b) unmanaged resources.