# Read file right after it was created and closed

Tags: c#, file

After creating a file via File.Create, I want to read it afterwards with File.ReadAllText. However, I always get an exception that says that the process cannot access the file. Once the file is created, access works without problems.
So I assume that the file is not yet released by File.Create at the time where it should be read. How do I solve this? Below is my method.

```
    public SettingsModel LoadSettings()
    {
        var _fullPath = FileHelper.GetFullPath(_fileName);
        if (!File.Exists(_fullPath))
        {
            File.Create(_fullPath).Close();
        }
        var serializedSettings = File.ReadAllText(_fullPath);
        var settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SettingsModel>(serializedSettings);

        if (settings == null)
        {
            return new SettingsModel();
        }
        else
        {
            return settings;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try using the [using clause pattern for IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) to be sure to free up Windows resources and handle, thus any own lock.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File being used by another process after using File.Create()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781357/file-being-used-by-another-process-after-using-file-create) and [Release resources in .Net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764075/release-resources-in-net-c-sharp)

Comment: @OlivierRogier Same issue with  using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(_fullPath, true)) { }

Comment: I've faced this problem with some trashy antivirus programs. After a file is closed they scan the file and you can't read it immediately.

Comment: Does the file exist before creating it? In all cases, put a breakpoint on the reading line and before executing it what does lockhunter say?

Comment: Lockhunter says that the file is blocked by its own application.

Comment: I must apologize, the mistake was between the ears. In the method GetFullPath, I already check if the file exists and create it if necessary. I still thank everyone for the support.

Answer (score 0):

You create an empty file to deserialize it afterwards. You can perform deserialization only if the file exists:

```cs
public SettingsModel LoadSettings()
{
    var _fullPath = FileHelper.GetFullPath(_fileName);
    var settings = File.Exists(_fullPath) 
        ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SettingsModel>(File.ReadAllText(_fullPath))
        : new SettingsModel();
    return settings;
}
```

Comment: While this is ok, the real problem is, that you can't read from a file immediatly after creation (*However, I always get an exception that says that the process cannot access the file*)

Comment: File.Create returns an (open) stream, so you have to close the returned Stream before reading:
`using (var fs = File.Create("myFile.txt")) { } var content = File.ReadAllText("myFile.txt");`

Comment: `File.Create(...).Close()` also closes the file. I would also put that in a using block instead, but in this case, the file can't be left open. If File.Create fails, there is no stream to close.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem either.

Comment: I must apologize, the mistake was between the ears. In the method GetFullPath, I already check if the file exists and create it if necessary. I still thank everyone for the support.

Comment: You can use *Path.GetFullPath(filename)* from System.IO namespace directly ;)