# FileMode and FileAccess and IOException: The process cannot access the file 'filename' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, process, ioexception

I have an application A that generates a text file for tracing.
While, an application B needs read the same text file and attach in a mailmessage.

But I get the following error, when application B try read the text file:

> IOException: The process cannot access the file 'filename' because it
>   is being used by another process

Any suggestions ? Maybe better use for FileMode and FileAccess?

Application A

```
if (File.Exists(nFile2)) File.Delete(nFile2);
                traceFile2 = File.Open(nFile2, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                if (traceFile2 != null)
                {
                    var twt2 = new TextWriterTraceListener(traceFile2);

                    // http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/20
                    try
                    {
                        if (twt2.Writer is StreamWriter)
                        {
                            (twt2.Writer as StreamWriter).AutoFlush = true;
                        }
                    }
                    catch { }

                    var indiceTraceFile2 = Trace.Listeners.Add(twt2);
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("INICIO: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Application B

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(f, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read))
                    {
                        var messageAttachment = new Attachment(fileStream, Path.GetFileName(f));
                        msgMail.Attachments.Add(messageAttachment);
                    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that both the service and the reader open the log file non-exclusively.  Notice line 2 of App A and Line 1 of App B

Application A:

```
if (File.Exists(nFile2)) 
    File.Delete(nFile2);
traceFile2 =  new FileStream(nFile2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
if (traceFile2 != null)
{
    var twt2 = new TextWriterTraceListener(traceFile2);
    // http://www.helixoft.com/blog/archives/20
    try
    {
        if (twt2.Writer is StreamWriter)
        {
            (twt2.Writer as StreamWriter).AutoFlush = true;
        }
    }
    catch { }

    var indiceTraceFile2 = Trace.Listeners.Add(twt2);
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("INICIO: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

and Application B:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(f, FileMode.Open, 
                                                 FileAccess.Read, 
                                                 FileShare.ReadWrite))
{
    var messageAttachment = new Attachment(fileStream, Path.GetFileName(f));
    msgMail.Attachments.Add(messageAttachment);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can read and write from/to the same file at the same time (by different threads/processes).

Here is a sample code. Just see how *FileStream* is created.

```
string fname = "a.txt";

//WRITER
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    var f = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    var s = new StreamWriter(f);
    long l = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        s.WriteLine(l++);
        s.Flush();
        Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
    }
});


//READER
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
    var f = new FileStream(fname, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    var s = new StreamReader(f);

    while (true)
    {
        var line = s.ReadLine();
        if (line == null) { Task.Delay(100).Wait(); continue; };
        Console.WriteLine("> " +  line + " <");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not using the Dispose() and Close() methods of StreamWriter class to release the file.

Comment: Not release the file in Application A, because App A is running. Both applications running in the same time.

Answer (score -1):

You need to release control of the file from Program A. Try closing or disposing the streamwriter when you finish.

Or you might attempt `using` as is described in the answer to this question: [Releasing access to files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8770234/releasing-access-to-files)

Comment: Even with `FileShare.ReadWrite`?

Comment: It seems some other answers invalidates this.

Comment: Not release the file in Application A, because App A is running. Both applications running in the same time.