# Normal close for modeless forms and open modal forms in using block. Enough?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dispose

Am developing an MDI Windows Forms Application.

From a welcome (Kind of like a home page) window, user can open specific windows to add or edit entities, say, an Order or a Customer.  Each of this opens in its own modeless window (as an MDIChild).
Adding a new record in some situations is done in a modal window.

I am NOT explicitly doing a Dispose() on the modeless windows.  As per examination during Debug, when the Close button of the forms are clicked, the Dispose() method in the Designer.cs file executes and the base.Disposing method is called.  I take that to understand that the form is indeed disposed off on clicking the close button.

For dialog windows, I am opening them within a using block, which as I understand, will Dispose off the window when the using block ends.

So, is my overall understanding and approach correct ?

I did google on this. Seems there are pretty strong supporters of different approaches, due to which I am a bit unsure if my approach is OK.

Would appreciate your clarifications.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: This is fine, no changes are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

you have the variable in a using block? you are pretty well off. Unless that class contains any unmanaged resources. C# dialogs and forms are not unmanaged. Most everything in C# is managed memory. So the using should be sufficient.

You have a using clause so the following doesn't really apply but it's good to know

*"Are IDisposables not disposed of when they go out of scope?"
No. If the IDisposable object is finalizable, which is not the same thing, then it will be finalized when it's garbage collected.
Which might be soon or might be almost never.*

Lots of discussion that should help you here for more information

[C# USING keyword - when and when not to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/317184/57883)

My current understanding is that unless you are using unmanaged resources the garbage collector or closing of the program will take care of it if it decides it needs the memory reclaimed or the program is closing in a stable state.